# grpc builder.BuildAndStart() hangs on aarch64 but not x86_64

Tags: c++, grpc

I have the grpc [route_guide example](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/cpp/) working on both aarch64 and x86_64 but when I translate this example into an already existing (CMake) project only x86_64 works. The aarch64 just hangs in server.BuildAndStart()

The code is identical for the 2 platforms:

```
  void RunServer(const std::string& db_path) {
  std::cout << "RunServer" << std::endl;
  std::string server_address("0.0.0.0:50051");
  RouteGuideImpl service(db_path);
  ServerBuilder builder;
  builder.AddListeningPort(server_address, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
  builder.RegisterService(&service);
  //builder.SetSyncServerOption(ServerBuilder::SyncServerOption::MAX_POLLERS,2); // Doesn't make a difference
  std::cout << "Before builder.BuildAndStart()" << std::endl;
  std::unique_ptr<grpc::Server> server(builder.BuildAndStart());
  std::cout << "After builder.BuildAndStart()" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Server listening on " << server_address << std::endl;
  server->Wait();
}
```

Using gdb I can see that x86_64 starts 1+4 threads and then listens for grpc traffic. It also works using any other example for route guide (e.g both in C++ and node) communicating with this.

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/me/mycode/grpc_project/build/myexecutable 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fffd0bd9700 (LWP 30537)]
RunServer
DB parsed, loaded 100 features.
Before builder.BuildAndStart()
[New Thread 0x7fffd03d8700 (LWP 30538)]
[New Thread 0x7fffcfbd7700 (LWP 30539)]
[New Thread 0x7fffcf3d6700 (LWP 30540)]
[New Thread 0x7fffcebd5700 (LWP 30541)]
After builder.BuildAndStart()
Server listening on 0.0.0.0:50051
```

But on the aarch64 platform only 1+2 threads are started then grpc hangs

```
Starting program: /home/ubuntu/mycode/grpc_project/build/myexecutable
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fab553030 (LWP 27568)]
RunServer
DB parsed, loaded 100 features.
Before builder.BuildAndStart()
[New Thread 0x7faad53030 (LWP 27569)]
[New Thread 0x7faa553030 (LWP 27570)]
```

Where to start debugging this and what could the root cause be?
Others (both here at SO and elsewhere) have suggested limiting the number of threads using ResourceQuota like this

```
grpc::ResourceQuota rq;
rq.SetMaxThreads(n); // n=1 or n=2
builder.SetResourceQuota(rq);
```

But it makes no difference, aarch64 still hangs

Ubuntu 16.04 with aarch64 (Nvidia TX2)

Comment: Any luck? I'm facing what seems to be a similar problem but on x86_64  after updating to 1.22.1. I'm suspecting bad configuration/installation of gpr_log

Comment: Interesting find @Eyal Fink, I think I'm using 1.23 for this. Which version did you use before updating to 1.22.1?

Comment: Still no news about this? Seems like i'm experiencing a similar issue with the same behaviour. But i'm running grpc on 32-Bit ARMv7.

Comment: @Ian which version of GRPC are you using?

Comment: @bits i'm using gRPC version 1.30.2. I'm sorry, i forgot to mention this.